# Is it possible to be immune to dark attacks?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

If I made a team comprised of 5 monster with the awoken ability to block dark attack at a 20% chance, would that mean that I would be immune to dark type attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you are talking about the "Sunglass" awoken skill, that's really 20% of avoiding Darkness. But the Darkness this awoken skill refers is the orbs changing to dark (in other words, there's 20% of chance to avoid abilities that turn all board into dark, not avoiding Dark element attacks). Check http://puzzledragonx.com and http://pad.wikia.com for more info.